# My custom dimensions do not capture values from my dataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I set up my dataLayer as follow:

```
    {
        "event": "viewContent",
        "ecommerce":     {
        "product":       {
        "id": "1043",
        "category":         [
        "All",
        "Basic Care",
        "Special Care",
        "Brands",
        "Skincare",
        "Referral Welcome",
        "Haze Collection",
        "All",
        "Brand"
       ],
        "name": "test",
        "brand": "Brand",
        "displayPrice": "21.0000",
        "basePrice": "13.0000",
         "currency": "USD"
```

and when I used Google Tag Manager to create custom dimensions in my GA tag, it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: This is not enough information (how do your variables to capture the values look like?). Also product category does not take an array as value, if you want to send a category hierarchy you have to use slashes ("firstcat/secondcat/thirdcat").

Comment: Apologies, rookie here. May I know what you mean by variables?

Comment: Supposedly you have set up GTM variables to catch the values from the datalayer which you then use in your GA tag in the custom variables section.

Comment: I only wanted to capture the product ID value for dynamic remarketing. However the developer built this dataLayer, and I used "id" as the variable and it's not returning any value when I tested it in Preview

Comment: @Harry the dataLayer is not complete or is not correct built, are you using enhance ecommerce?,  which action is this? a purchase? in this case, you can build a var that collects ecommerce.product.id[0] . But what you want to do when you have 2 or more products?

Comment: Yes I'm using Enhanced Ecommerce. This action is for product view. I want to retarget to people who have viewed this specific product.

Comment: @KemenPaulosPlaza Can you explain a lil bit more on the ecommerce.product.id[0]? Do I have to add this in the variable for custom dimension in GTM?